# Example IdentityServer 4 refresh token flow for Hybrid with Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have configured my client to use Hybrid flow with a grant type of password and offline. The user is able to generate an access token and the response does include a refresh token.

My question is I do not see documentation on how to use the refresh token for non .Net environments. Specifically I am curious if any body has a sample refresh flow in another language or Postman that shows which endpoints to hit and what the request needs to look like when the user requests a new token via the refresh token.

Thanks in advance,
G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented at http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html

> The token endpoint can be used to programmatically request tokens. It supports the password, authorization_code, client_credentials and refresh_token grant types). Furthermore the token endpoint can be extended to support extension grant types.

Example

> POST /connect/token client_id=client1&client_secret=secret&    grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=hdh922&redirect_uri=https://myapp.com/callback